# Graphics problem on debian 8.0 with Kaby Lake CPU

Tags: debian, xorg, intel

I'm having some problems with the graphical configuration of a fresh Debian 8 install: things like HTML Canvas, Videos, Games etc. are insanely slow.

I spent some time trying to fix things in the `xorg.conf` file but it hasn't changed anything atm .

Here is the Device section of my `xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "modesetting"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

I get this in `glxinfo`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

And the informations I find relevant in the `Xorg.log` file:

```
[     1.689] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     1.689]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     1.689]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[     1.689]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[     1.689]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[     1.689] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     2.427] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:5912:1458:d000 rev 4, Mem @ 0xee000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     2.428] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     2.428] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     2.430] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     2.436] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.436]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.436]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[     2.436] (==) AIGLX enabled
[     2.436] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     2.436] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     2.436] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[     2.436] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[     2.445] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.445]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.445]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     2.445] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     2.445] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     2.446] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.446]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 0.9.0
[     2.446]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.446]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[     2.446] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
...
[     3.916] (==) modesetting(0): Backing store enabled
[     3.916] (==) modesetting(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     3.916] (II) modesetting(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[     3.977] (==) modesetting(0): DPMS enabled
[     3.977] (WW) modesetting(0): Option "AccelMethod" is not used
[     4.077] (--) RandR disabled
[     4.087] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     4.088] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[     4.088] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[     4.150] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[     4.150] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

Here is my kernel version : `4.11.0-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.11-1~exp2 (2017-05-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks for your help, feel free to answer more details if you want.

**Edit** : Updating to Debian 9 fixed the problem

Comment: Obviously your kernel is new enough, but I suspect you’re missing the firmware (you’re running with software 3D, no acceleration).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer Stephen, I tried the solution you gave on the other question but it didn't changed anything. Intel firmware is worst as I get tons of artifacts and glitches.

Comment: Could you try with the 4.9 kernel from Jessie backports? That gives good results with the packaged firmware on Kaby Lake systems. In any case you can’t get 3D acceleration on modern Intel GPUs without the firmware.

Comment: I should mention that it was the first kernel I tried, sorry. I upgraded to the 4.11 because I read that there was improvements on Kaby Lake support in 4.10 for the power management and 4.11 for the audio. Audio is working well now but I doesn't changed anything for graphics. Are you sure that my question is a duplicate of the one you gave?

Comment: For graphics support, yes, I’m pretty sure the answer to the other question is relevant. I would expect the 4.9 kernel with associated firmware to behave correctly on Kaby Lake, as far as graphics go at least. Later kernels may need newer firmware than what’s available in the packages.

Comment: I should add that I’m perfectly willing to re-open the question if you think that’s appropriate.

Comment: Okay, I will try again with the 4.9 kernel. What makes me think that it's not a duplicate is because I don't get errors like "no screens found". Thanks again for taking time to answer

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem with 4.9 Kernel :(.

Comment: With the firmware installed?

Comment: If you *do* have the firmware installed, you could try deleting the `Device` section of your `xorg.conf`, and perhaps upgrading Mesa (start with `libgl1-mesa-dri`, version 13 is available in Jessie backports).

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately I still have the problem :(. When I deleted the Device section, Xorg took back the Intel driver which still show so much graphical artifacts. Uninstalling `xserver-xorg-video-intel` made Xorg use modesetting but the problem is still here. My `Xorg.log` is the same as before except that there is no line saying `Option "AccelMethod" is not used`.

Comment: You will find the full xorg.log file [here](https://gist.github.com/MrHalfman/8f2996e97b0c4edefaf8ff919ff89ae4) (My last test was made on 4.11, problem is the same on 4.9)

Comment: You’re still getting the “AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable” message, which suggests the firmware isn’t being loaded. Are there any `i915` firmware-related messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: I think that you are right, [here](https://gist.github.com/MrHalfman/8b85364035c46beac7029ff064e548dc) is what I get from a `dmesg | grep i915`. It seems like the driver is not fully loaded.